# Is there a solution to the problem es_extended Fivem

Tags: esx

problem = SCRIPT ERROR: es_extended:modules/**core**/player/server/events.lua:150: attempt to index a nil value (field 'UsableItemsCallbacks')

> task (es_extended:modules/**core**/player/server/events.lua:150)
> processQueue (@async/async.lua:67)
> parallelLimit (@async/async.lua:86)
> ref (es_extended:modules/**core**/player/server/module.lua:180)
> (@mysql-async/mysql-async.js:15543)

Answer (score 0):

This error is because of some wrong configuration(happened with me a while ago before I stopped using ESX). Recheck your config files and if that still doesn't work try disabling the ESX default loadscreen. Lastly, set up clean ESX again and see if that works.